# SAM conversion in Kotlin (Lambda expression)

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I have the following functional interface defined in Java.

```
interface OnButtonSwitchedListener {
    fun onButtonSwitched(isLogin: Boolean)
}
```

Now, the problem is when I have to use this in Kotlin, I have to create an anonymous object to use this interface like so,

```
binding.button.setOnButtonSwitched(object: OnButtonSwitchedListener{
                    override fun onButtonSwitched(isLogin: Boolean) {
                        binding.root
                            .setBackgroundColor(
                                ContextCompat.getColor(
                                    this@AuthActivity,
                                     if(isLogin) R.color.colorPrimary else R.color.lb_secondPage))
                    }
                })
```

However, the syntax is Java8 is a lot smarter,

```
binding.button.setOnButtonSwitched(isLogin -> {
                binding.root
                    .setBackgroundColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                        this,
                        isLogin ? R.color.colorPrimary : R.color.secondPage));
            })
```

Is there any way, I can write similar lambda expression in Kotlin too?

I tried the following but it throws an error shown in the inset image.

```
setOnButtonSwitched{isLogin -> {binding.root
                    .setBackgroundColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                            this@AuthActivity,
                            if(isLogin) R.color.colorPrimary else R.color.lb_secondPage))}}
```

[image: Error message in Android Studio]

Comment: Use lambdas https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Comment: Yes, That's what I'm trying to do, however it errors out on the lambdaexpression as mentioned on my question.

Comment: You should define your interface as `fun interface ..` as described in release notes of Kotlin 1.4 https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SAM Conversions are going to be introduced in Kotlin 1.4](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/12/what-to-expect-in-kotlin-1-4-and-beyond#language-features), until then you have to manually implement the interface and override the function for now.

They'll look the same as a normal lambda:

```kotlin
binding.button.setOnButtonSwitched{ isLogin ->
    ...
}
```

**PS: Expected release of Kotlin 1.4 is on Spring 2020**

---

**For current version Kotlin 1.3.xx**

If you use these too often, then try creating a utility function for now:

```kotlin
fun OnButtonSwitchedListener(block: (Boolean) -> Unit) =
    object : OnButtonSwitchedListener {
        override fun onButtonSwitched(isLogin: Boolean) {
            block(isLogin)
        }
    }
```

Now you can call like this:

```kotlin
binding.button.setOnButtonSwitched(OnButtonSwitchedListener { isLogin ->
   ... // your code
})
```

Comment: Thanks, until then whats the alternative lambda expression?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the interface is actually in Java, not in Kotlin (`void onButtonSwitched(boolean isLogin)` instead of `fun onButtonSwitched(isLogin: Boolean)`), you need to remove `{}` around the lambda's body (the part after `isLogin ->`):

```
setOnButtonSwitched { isLogin -> binding.root
                    .setBackgroundColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                            this@AuthActivity,
                            if(isLogin) R.color.colorPrimary else R.color.lb_secondPage)) }
```

The problem is that the way you wrote it makes a lambda which doesn't call `binding.root.setBackgroundColor(...)` but instead creates another lambda `{ binding.root.setBackgroundColor(...) }` and throws it away.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm getting the same error as in the picture.

Comment: If your interface really has `fun onButtonSwitched(isLogin: Boolean)` it isn't defined in Java.

Comment: The Interface OnButtonSwitchedListener  is defined in java.